# Obfuscation not work for kotlin classes and fields name

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard, android-r8

I am developing an *Android SDK* in *kotlin* and trying to obfuscate it.
The *R8* obfuscation works fine on *java* classes but not work for *kt* classes.

Do anyone know how to obfuscate *kotlin* classes and field names?

I wrote 4 classes:
[image: structure on Android Studio]

**src:**
*KotlinClassToKeep.kt*

```kotlin
class KotlinClassToKeep {
    var kotlinClassToObfuscate = KotlinClassToObfuscate()

    fun funToKeep() {
        kotlinClassToObfuscate.funToObfuscate()
        Log.d("TAG", "here in kotlin")
    }
}
```

*KotlinClassToObfuscate.kt*

```kotlin
class KotlinClassToObfuscate{
    var obfuscateStr: String = "default"

    fun funToObfuscate() {
        Log.d("TAG", obfuscateStr)
    }
}
```

*JavaClassToObfuscate.java*

```java
public class JavaClassToKeep {
    public JavaClassToObfuscate javaClassToObfuscate;

    public void methodToKeep() {
        javaClassToObfuscate.methodToObfuscate();
        Log.d("TAG", "here in java");
    }
}
```

*JavaClassToObfuscate.java*

```java
class JavaClassToObfuscate {

    public String strToObfuscate = "default";

    public void methodToObfuscate() {
        Log.d("TAG", strToObfuscate);
    }
}
```

*proguard-rules.pro*

```
-repackageclasses 'obfuscate.test.obfuscate'

-keep class obfuscate.test.java.JavaClassToKeep {
    *;
}

-keep class obfuscate.test.kotlin.KotlinClassToKeep {
    *;
}
```

Then, I packed this library.
Bu when I use *JD-GUI* to check it, there are some information I wanted to obfuscate like `KotlinClassToObfuscate` on it.

```
@Metadata(mv = {1, 5, 1}, k = 1, xi = 48, d1 = {"\000\032\n\002\030\002\n\002\020\000\n\002\b\002\n\002\020\016\n\002\b\005\n\002\020\002\n\000\030\0002\0020\001B\005\006\002\020\002J\006\020\t\032\0020\nR\032\020\003\032\0020\004X\016\006\016\n\000\032\004\b\005\020\006\"\004\b\007\020\b\006\013"}, d2 = {"Lobfuscate/test/kotlin/KotlinClassToObfuscate;", "", "()V", "obfuscateStr", "", "getObfuscateStr", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "setObfuscateStr", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "funToObfuscate", "", "obfuscate-test_release"})
public final class b {}
```

And when I use an application project to use this SDK, I can see the class name and val name on it:
[structure on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYTvW.png)
[image: After decompile]

But the java class is obfuscated as I expect:

[image: obfuscated java class]

Here is the mapping.txt generated after build:

```
# compiler: R8
# compiler_version: 2.1.75
# pg_map_id: 2e561a0
# common_typos_disable
obfuscate.test.java.JavaClassToObfuscate -> obfuscate.test.obfuscate.a:
obfuscate.test.kotlin.KotlinClassToKeep -> obfuscate.test.kotlin.KotlinClassToKeep:
    1:1:void obfuscate.test.kotlin.KotlinClassToObfuscate.funToObfuscate():0:0 -> funToKeep
    1:1:void funToKeep():0 -> funToKeep
    2:2:void funToKeep():0:0 -> funToKeep
obfuscate.test.kotlin.KotlinClassToObfuscate -> obfuscate.test.obfuscate.b:
```

It also shows that `KotlinClassToObfuscate` would be obfuscated, but the truth is it's not totally obfuscated.
Do anyone know how to obfuscate kotlin classes and field names?

Comment: Try to use Proguard in your release flavor:             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: I tried adding it in the BuildType and the java class was obfuscated successfully.  
The generated mapping file is on the post.